# While loop output explanation

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

new learner, unable to under stand the output of the following program.

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]
while(i < len(PlayListRatings) and Rating >= 6):
    print(Rating)
    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
    i = i + 1
```

**Output**

```
10
10
9.5
10
8
7.5
```

why 10, 10 are together? why there is third 10? why didn't wile loop break on 5?

Comment: Because `i` in incremented after `Rating = PlayListRatings[i]`

Answer (score 0):

If you move `i = i + 1` statement in `while` loop one line up, your code will be working correctly.

Comment: thanks for your time and guidance. now the output is as per my logic. but i am stuck, what was happening before?

Comment: Before you were assigning PlayListRatings[0] to Rating variable twice. Before iterating through while loop and at the first iteration of the while loop. Now when you increase i by 1 before assigning a value to Rating variable in the while loop, it will assign PlayListRating[1] to Rating variable at the first iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

First will split out individual lines so that it will be easy for you to understand.

`PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]`

Here you declared an ARRAY of numbers, whenever you pick the `0th` index of the array will become `10`.

`i = 0` // Here you declared an iterator with an initial value `0`

`Rating = PlayListRatings[0]`
As I said, here in this line `Rating` variable initialization will have the value `10` as it is the `0th` index of Array

```
while(i < len(PlayListRatings) and Rating >= 6):
    print(Rating)
    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
    i = i + 1
```

So, In the loop, the initial condition will be the iterator `i` less than `8` (total length of the Array) AND `Rating` greater than or equal to `6` of course it is as it contains the `0th` index value `10` from the Array. So that this loop will only break until the value `5` is replaced in the `Rating` variable and that is after `7.5`.

Here then the first print will be `10` then in every iteration the `Rating` variable is replaced by 0,1,2... index values respectively, so that 10(default value in Rating variable first), 10(0th index), 9.5 (1st index), 10 (2nd index) such as.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. then why loop didn't break when 5>=6 reached?